# How to show that $H=\langle a,b\rangle=\{a^m\cdot{b^n}\mid m,n\in{\mathbb{Z}}\}$ is a subgroup of $\langle G,\cdot\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I have $a,b\in{G}$ and also $G$ is Abelian.

I thought that first I should show that $H\subset{G}$ and then show that $\forall{h_1,h_2}\in{H}$ we will have $ h_1\cdot{h_2}\in{H}$.

First to show that $H$ is a subset of $G$, I have taken $a^m\cdot{b^n}\in{H}$.
Since $a,b\in{G}$ we have $a^m\cdot{b^n}\in{G}$ from the closure axiom.
Secondly to show that $H$ is subgroup I think I need to show first that $H$ is also Abelian but I'm having difficulties approaching this proof.

If I prove that $H$ is Abelian then if I take $h_1=a^m\cdot{b^n},h_2=a^x\cdot{b^y}\in{H}$. Then $$h_1\cdot{h_2}=a^m\cdot{b^n}\cdot{a^x}\cdot{b^y}=a^{m+x\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\cdot{b^{n+y\in{\mathbb{Z}}}}\in{H}.$$

Is this the correct approach? If yes the how can I show that $H$ is Abelian ?

Comment: $H$ is abelian because $G$ is abelian. It inherits the group operation from $G$.

Comment: I tend to take the two-step approach https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test

Comment: @Bungo Is that always the case ?

Comment: @user3133165 Yes, any subgroup of an abelian group is abelian. Proof: if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $a,b \in H$, then $a,b$ are also in $G$, and $G$ is abelian, hence $ab = ba$. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is the [One-step Subgroup Test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:~:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

You have shown that $H\subseteq G$.

We have $e=a^0b^0\in H$, so $H\neq\varnothing$.

Let $g=a^nb^m, h=a^rb^s\in H$ for $n,m,r,s\in\Bbb Z$. Then

$$\begin{align}
gh^{-1}&=(a^nb^m)(a^rb^s)^{-1}\\
&=(a^nb^m)(b^{-s}a^{-r})\\
&=a^n(b^m(b^{-s}a^{-r}))\\
&=a^n((b^mb^{-s})a^{-r})\\
&=a^n(b^{m-s}a^{-r})\\
&=a^n(a^{-r}b^{m-s})\quad (G\, (\text{ and hence } H)\text{ is abelian})\\
&=(a^na^{-r})b^{m-s}\\
&=a^{n-r}b^{m-s},
\end{align}$$

but $n-r, m-s\in\Bbb Z$. Hence $gh^{-1}\in H$.

Hence $H\le G$.

(It is not necessary to check whether $H$ is abelian to verify that it is a subgroup. However, since I made use of commutativity, consider that for any $p,q\in H\subseteq G$, we have $pq=qp$ since $G$ is abelian.  Hence $H$ is abelian. )

Comment: I am familiar with that test yes. But could you please add the exact steps before the final result $a^{n-r}b^{m-s}$ for me to understand.Because I can't see how you reached that from the associative axiom. I see that $$(a^nb^m)(b^{-s}a^{-r})=a^n(b^{m}b^{-s})a^{-r}=a^{n}b^{m-s}a^{-r}$$

Comment: I've edited my answer now, @user3133165. Is that any better?

Comment: Forgive me if I don't understand yet. but could you explain why is it OK to do $a^n(a^{-r}b^{m-s})$. I now understand that you can do that because $a^n,a^{-r},b^{m-s}\in{G}$. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, @user3133165.

Comment: Much appreciated that helped.

Comment: You're welcome, @user3133165.